# 2d char vector printing spaces when printing second column

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, stdstring

Here I have a 2d vector of char -

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> solution = {
 {"O","1"}, 
 {"T","0"}, 
 {"W","9"}, 
 {"E","5"}, 
 {"N","4"}
};
```

Printing anything from first column - prints fine.

```
cout << "In main - " << solution [ 1 ] [ 0 ]; // Prints T
```

But when I try to access element of second column.

```
cout << "In main - " << solution [ 1 ] [ 1 ]; // Prints blank space - I can't seem to understand why's the case.
```

After quiet amount of searching I tried by putting single quotes around every element.

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> solution = {
  {'O','1'}, 
  {'T','0'}, 
  {'W','9'}, 
  {'E','5'}, 
  {'N','4'}
};
```

It works fine in this case.

```
cout << "In main - " << solution [ 1 ] [ 1 ]; // Gives me 0 in this case.
```

Now why is it that I'm getting blank spaces when accessing second column in `"" double quotes`  scene.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing a vector<int> with 2 string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835713/constructing-a-vectorint-with-2-string-literals) TL;DR the first program has UB, so it might give any result.

Comment: I saw it somehow is related to my problem but doesn't explain or I didn't understood it. What's "TL:DR, UB"? I don't have range based loop, and second thing is it only happens with this string and one other string all other strings all working perfectly. Out of 10 test cases only 2 failed and they both have same problem printing either invalid character or spaces.

Comment: Sorry, TL;DR means "too long, didn't read". I've added an answer below that also explains UB.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, for each element of `solution`, you are trying to construct a `vector<char>` from 2 string literals. This will use the constructor of `vector` that takes 2 iterators (since string literals can be converted to pointers). Since the pointers are not denoting a valid range, this invokes undefined behavior (UB).

In the second example, for each element of `solution`, you are trying to construct a `vector<char>` from 2 `char`s, which is perfectly fine, and gives you the result you expected.

Comment: Anyway to tackle this? As input isn't really in my hand, and it will always be in string literals.