# Constructing a vector<int> with 2 string literals

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

For the following program:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = {"a", "b"};
  
  for(int i : v)
    std::cout << i << " ";   
}
```

clang prints `97 0`. The ascii value of `'a'` is 97, but I don't fully understand the output.

On the other hand, gcc throws an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()
```

so I assume it's using the 2 argument constructor that takes the size and default value, where the size is computed from the address of the string literal `"a"`.

If the program is well-formed, what is the correct behavior? Here's the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/r9zsn7).

Comment: I think `"a"` and `"b"` implicitly convert to `const char *` and it thinks it's a range of `char` which would be convertible to `int`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So just UB because the pointers are not pointing to the same range?

Comment: I think so. I think I've seen this before, I'm checking for a duplicate.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I couldn't find one.

Comment: I was thinking of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507602/why-does-the-number-of-elements-in-a-initializer-list-cause-an-ambiguous-call-er) which is related but not a duplicate.

Comment: Similar issue:[2d char vector printing spaces when printing the second column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62831470/2d-char-vector-printing-spaces-when-printing-second-column)

Comment: @JeJo It's basically the same underlying issue. I came up with this question while trying to figure out that one :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I assume it's using the 2 argument constructor that takes the size and default value

No, it's using the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking two input iterators. `"a"` and `"b"` could decay to pointer which is valid iterator. As the pointer (iterator) to `const char`, the dereferenced `const char` would be converted to `int` and added as the `vector`'s element. Anyway the code has UB because `"a"` and `"b"` don't refer to valid range, `"b"` is not reachable from `"a"`.